# Can not run validation on a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have created a form which has multiple input for each record and I hide/show them on demand.

The problem is when they are editable I want to validate the values without form submit.

```
<form action="Update" method="post" id="frmUpdateGroup" class="frmUpdateGroup">
    <div>
        <input id="Name_1" name="Name_1" required class="grp-Name form-control form-control-flat" value="zzzzz" />
    </div>
    <div style="display:none">
        <input id="Name_2" name="Name_2" required class="grp-Name form-control form-control-flat" value="" />
    </div>
```

```js
var $updateGroupNameValidator;

$('.frmUpdateGroup').validate({});

$updateGroupNameValidator = $('.grp-Name').validate({
    rules: {
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 50,
        required: true
    },
    messages: {
        required: "group name can not be null or empty",
        minlength: "group name must be at least 3 characters long",
        maxlength: "group name can not exceed 50 characters"
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addclass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeclass('has-error');
    },
    errorelement: 'span',
    errorclass: 'help-block',
    errorplacement: function(error, element) {
        debugger;
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertafter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertafter(element);
        }
    }
});

$('.grp-Name').blur(function(e) {
    $updateGroupNameValidator.valid();
});
$('.grp-Name').keyup(function(e) {
    $updateGroupNameValidator.valid();
});
```

I have created the form [JFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/cbb7yabv/1/) and expect to see error when the first textbox is cleared or input text is less than 3 characters, but noıthing happens.

Comment: The `.validate()` method can only be attached to the `form` element.  Period.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a guru of the validator plugin, but I think you can't define validator on a single element like you did, only defining rules for each element inside form validation handler like in the example below:

```js
var validator =  $("#frmUpdateGroup").validate({
         // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            Name_1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 50
            },
        },
        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            Name_1: {
                required: "group name can not be null or empty",
                minlength: "group name must be at least 3 characters long",
                maxlength: "group name can not exceed 50 characters"
            },
        },
    });

$('.grp-Name').keyup(function(e) {
   $('#Name_1').valid();
   // or $("#frmUpdateGroup").data('validator').element('#Name_1').valid();
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form action="Update" method="post" id="frmUpdateGroup" class="frmUpdateGroup">
    <div>
        <input id="Name_1" name="Name_1" required class="grp-Name form-control form-control-flat" value="zzzzz" />
    </div>
    <div style="display:none">
        <input id="Name_2" name="Name_2" required class="grp-Name form-control form-control-flat" value="" />
    </div>
    </form>
```